# How do I output a button and a text when I hover on an image? Do I need to use JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm working on my wordpress website right now, and there's one section where I have to create a gallery where the pictures would show some text and a button under the text when you over on the image.
I'm trying to use a:hover but I can only make some changes. How do I show a button when you hover on the image?
Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks a bunch

Comment: You need to use a client side scripting language like JavaScript or one of its libraries.

Comment: Any code will be appreciated. Showcase your code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example for you. You probably need to modify it to fill your needs.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/829mL4z1/1/

HTML markup

```
 <div class="holder">
    <img alt="your-alt" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png"/>
    <div class="info">
       My text<br/>
       <input type="button" value="Button"/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.holder').on('mouseenter',function(){
      $(this).find('.info').fadeIn();
      });

   $('.holder').on('mouseleave',function(){
      $('.info').fadeOut();
      });
  });
```

CSS

```
.holder{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100px;
  }

.info{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  }

img{
 width: 100px;
 }
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for!! thanks alot, but how do I implement this on my wordpress? Do I have to put in the Jquery script on my header.php on the child theme?

Comment: Well, I am not very familiar with wordspress... but you defientely need to add the jQuery library to your page. Then usually, I put the document ready script within script tags, below the HTML end tag. If this answer was useful for you and helped you solve your problem. Please mark it as the correct one so that others with similar problems can benefit from this answer as well.

Comment: Got it to work! love you! Thanks <3  Now all I need to do is make these images have Masonry style, like the brick wall thing. I need J query too for this. ugh, are you familiar with the Masonry?

Comment: By the way, how do I customize the Jscript so that I can use more class than just .holder?

Comment: Go nuts and add more class names to the selector `$('.holder, .otherClass')` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <img src="thing.jpg">
   <button>Blah</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper button { display: none; }
#wrapper:hover button { display: block; }
```

I'll leave you to handle the positioning.

Comment: Or for a better effect give img and buttom position: absolute with top (or right, left, bottom) -10000px, then on hover top:20px (or such). you can add a transition css to that and you could have a nice easy effect. (or play with opacity for a "fade" effect) many things to play with on hover with no javascript

Answer (score 0):

For all events in a web page, generally we prefer scripting languages like **Javascript** and **Jquery** . One simple example using jQuery is depicted in the following link. You can see all three sections: HTML, CSS, Javascript and the Output simultaneously here:

[Example](http://jsbin.com/kupifijiwiki/1/edit)